# TypeScript intersection types of functions

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

Intersection types of function types don't behave as I would expect them to. Take this sample:

```
var c: ((x: number) => void) = x => { };
```

This compiles just fine. `x` is a number in the lambda.

But this fails:

```
var c: ((x: number) => void) & ((x: number | string) => void) = x => { };
```

It says "x implicitly has an 'any' type". (Compiling with --noExplicitAny.)

Even this fails with the same remark:

```
var c: ((x: number) => void) & ((x: number) => void) = x => { };
```

That means that the not for all types `T`, `T & T` is the same as `T`, which is really weird.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think type intersection was meant to be used this way. It might be that the compiler just fails to calculate the type of x and assigns any which fails because of the compiler option.

It's also much clearer to just define multiple types for x itself, instead of joining the types of the two functions.

```js
var c: ((x: number | string) => void)  = x => { };
```